# Loop through json array string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Using the following code, I am getting the json array string in the div (named `remoteFeed`)
Say it shows:

```
{"id":"25","name":"Basil","country":"USA"}
```

My question is how can I get the json array elements?

Pl note that even though it shows the value in the div -- the alert (see below) shows blank!!!

```
alert(data);  //-------------------Shows blank
```

NB: Being a newbie I was trying to get the value first. But in this case we have to convert it to json object. So if you know a better way, so that I get the values (id, name..) on the client side that is more advisable

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#remoteFeed').load('http://testservice/json/');

  var data = remoteFeed.innerHTML;
  alert(data);  //-------------------Shows blank

  /*
              var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + data + ")"));
              for(var i in jsonObj)
            {
            var id = data[i].country_code;
            alert(id);
            }

  */
});
})(jQuery);


 var data = remoteFeed.innerHTML;
  alert(data);

</script>

</head>
<body>

      <div id="remoteFeed"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: pl provide complete code - not code fragment

Comment: I think you need to use callback function of `.load()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why the `alert()` is blank**

You're getting a blank value in the `alert()` call because you're not waiting for the `load()` request to complete. Instead of immediately alerting the value, consider passing a callback function to `load()`. The callback function is executed once the request is completed.

For example:

```
$('#remoteFeed').load('http://testservice/json/', function() {
    alert($('#remoteFeed').html());
});
```

**How to treat a JSON string as an object**

Basically, you can use the native `JSON` object in modern browsers to parse a JSON string into an object.

For example:

```
var json_object = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

Alternatively, you'll be far better off using one of [jQuery's other AJAX functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), that are more suitable to this task than `load()` which is meant for loading HTML.

For example:

```
$.getJSON('http://testservice/json/', function(json_object) {
    for(var i in json_object) {
       var id = json_object[i].country_code;
       alert(id);
    }
});
```

In this example the method `$.getJSON()` performs an AJAX request, assumes the returned data is in JSON format and automatically parses it for you. The callback function is then passed the resulting JSON object.

Comment: Can u pl provide the full code? I modified the code as below, but not working --------------                                    (function ($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('http://testservice/json/', function(json_data) {
    for(var i in json_data) {
       var id = json_data[i].country_code;
       alert(id);
    }
});
})(jQuery);

Comment: There is no full code. I'm following your example. Based on the code in your comment, it seems you have a syntax error. You're missing a closing `})` for the `document.ready` call. Anyway, you don't need to wrap this call with the immediately executing function, just do `$(document).ready(function() { $.getJSON... })`

Answer (score 0):

To get json result data you can use jQuery.getJSON() method

refer the jquery site http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: None of the above soln is working. The sample in the url you given is working but instead of parse xml tags (in http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?) I need to parse json.

Comment: Hello , As you want fliker api data in json you just need to add format=json.
[http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json]